# How can I use an image as a map?

Tags: ios, ios4, dictionary, geolocation, imagemap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone, Map, Clickable non-rectangular areas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870631/iphone-map-clickable-non-rectangular-areas)

I want to use an image as a map (without using MapKit) by defining zones on the image and allowing the user to tap one part of the image to show more details (that zone's features and such).

Could anyone please tell me how I could do that? (i.e., define zones on an image)?

Answer (score 1):

Someone in answering [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870631/iphone-map-clickable-non-rectangular-areas) suggests using CGPath to do this.  These will allow non-rectangular clickable areas like HTML imagemaps.

Comment: I will flag this question as a duplicate - i hope the answer was useful however