# Xcode : how can I use an image as map?

Tags: ios, mapkit

my question on iphone development
I want to use an image as a map. As  the overlay images in google Earth?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use [CGPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html) to do this.

You can find more information about this : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870631/iphone-map-clickable-non-rectangular-areas)

Comment: Please try to research a bit on your own, or at least google for a guide.